# Is cmd_vel output from Ros2_control a good way to control motors in a diff-drive robot?

Tags: ros-humble, diff-drive-controller, ros2-controllers

Ros2_Control allows controlling motors through low-level (fast) interfaces. But these can be tricky to set up. Does the cmd_vel topic from the controller originate from the same place in code? I mean, is a separate node subscribing to this topic going to allow the same precise control of robot movement? The cmd_vel topic from the teleop_twist_joy module will have a different topic name, of course, to keep these commands separate.

My rover robot uses Ros2 Humble and Ubuntu 22.04 server on Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference in cmd_vel and cmd_vel_out is that the joint_limits are applied for the latter. Why you want to use the diff_drive controller then at all? The benefit is that the vehicle kinematics is calculated and proper motor commands are sent to the hardware, plus odometry from wheel sensors. Have you seen the [DiffBot example](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_2/doc/userdoc.html)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am using the Diffbot example. I haven't been able to get the Ros2_control working with the Pigpio module on Raspberry Pi. I believe I have the encoder data going through, but the motor commands don't work yet.

Comment: First, is your setup working with the hardware plugin from the demo? 
Second, if you have a working node accepting values via topic, you can use [the topic based hardware component](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/topic_based_ros2_control) for testing. Then figure out, how to write a custom plugin, e.g. from [this](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_7/doc/userdoc.html#writing-a-hardware-interface) tutorial

Comment: Well, that looks complicated. My rover doesn't have an arm or those joints. I'd better concentrate on just driving under Ros2_control at first, no?

Comment: ros2_control is not designed to use the controllers and send controller outputs via topics to nodes interfacing with the hardware. You can use the topic_based_hardware_component from above (maybe out of the box), but you should consider writing your own hardware component. See [this tutorial](https://articulatedrobotics.xyz/mobile-robot-13-ros2-control-real/) for example on how to write that for an arduino.